# Internet connection not working on guest system (VirtualBox, Guest: Ubuntu, Host: Windows)

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, connection

I have the VirtualBox 5.1.22 installed and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on it. My host system is Windows 7. When I installed everything, the VirtualBox/Ubuntu seem to have configured the network connection correctly by themselves. I am working on my company's computer and the company changed the firewall. After that, the connection on my guest Ubuntu system is not working anymore. If a ping for example google, there seems to be a connection, but if a want to load google in a browser, it does not load anything. Same with other websites. I was told that that's because of the change of the firewall and that I have to reconfigure my VirtualBox. But I do not really find what I have to change. The ping between guest and host does work.

I would be very happy if you could give me some tips what I have to change to reconfigure. I read in some forums that I might have to change the IPv4 address, I tried but it didn't help.

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Pato

Comment: Not enough info.  How is your VM connecting (Bridged interface, NAT, ??)  What change was made on your work network? Do you need to now use a proxy?

Comment: The VB is connecting via NAT, actually I did not configure anything about the network connections, NAT was the default mode when I installed the VirtualBox and I could immediately access the internet. Then, my company changed the firewall (I don't know more details) and since then, the internetaccess on my VB is not working anymore. They told me, the internet problems are due to the Firewall change and that I have to reconfigure the network configurations. But as far as I understand, NAT should be working without any configuration. The internet connection on my host computer is working fine.

Comment: You need to find otu what changed.  Are they white listing via MAC address? Using some auth scheme like X.25?

Comment: They didn't give me much more info, they just told me that I would have to fix it by my own searching in the internet how it's done.. So I guessed that from their side everything is ok with my VB accessing the internet that it's just reconfiguring somehow the VB from my side in a general way.. So you'd say, I need more information from the IT folks?

Comment: Ok, I could resolve it. I had to configure a proxy, now I can access the internet.